# How to solve the following equation for g?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on an equation I figured out:

> $$x = \frac{(g - g_1)\sin(60°) + r }{g}$$

where $g_1$, $r$ and $x$ are already given.
At the end I want the equation to be solved for $g$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We use something called MathJax here to format mathematics in questions and answers, making them easier for everyone to read (and it just looks really nice). I edited your question to include MathJax, and you can see what I did by clicking "edit" below the body of your question. If you want to learn how to do it for yourself, here's a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. It's pretty easy to pick up!

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\sin 60° = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ and then

$$x = \frac{(g - g_1) \cdot \sin(60°) + r} g \iff xg=(g - g_1) \cdot \sin(60°) + r $$

$$xg- g\sin(60°) =- g_1\sin(60°) + r $$

$$g\left(x- \sin(60°)\right) =- g_1\sin(60°) + r $$

$$g =\frac{- g_1\sin(60°) + r}{x- \sin(60°)} $$

Comment: I know! This is where I was multiple times, but I didnt know how to proceed. I already multiplied everything inside the brackets, tried to get rid of the **sin (60°)** and it failed. When I divided by x _(after your last step)_, I wasn't able to move the **(g - g1)** to the left since it is chained to the **sind(60°)** through multiplication. I know what everything means here, just not sure about the conversion.

Comment: @HeLlOwOrLd I add some step more.

Comment: @HeLlOwOrLd Can you conlcude now?

Answer (score 0):

Writing
$a$ for $\sin(60)$,

$\begin{array}\\
x 
&= \dfrac{(g - g1) * a + r }{ g}\\
&= \dfrac{g*a - g1 * a + r }{ g}\\
&= a+\dfrac{- g1 * a + r }{ g}\\
\text{so}\\
x-a
&= \dfrac{- g1 * a + r }{ g}\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac1{x-a}
&= \dfrac{ g}{- g1 * a + r }\\
\text{or}\\
g
&=\dfrac{- g1 * a + r }{x-a}\\
\end{array}
$